# Change label text before file read happens

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I haven't used java in awhile and I am trying to do something like this in one main class:

```
// do stuff
this.label.setText("Status: IDLE");
// do things
this.label.setText("Status: LOADING..."); // set to loading right before file read
// read and parse huge file
this.label.setText("Status: DONE");
```

I want the label to show 'loading...' as the large file read is being executed but the label never freezes (as the job is being ran). How can I force the label to change during read? Do I need to use separate class/thread? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I force the label to change during read? Do I need to use
>   separate class/thread?

Yes, you are right. The label and the class that is changing it's value should be in different threads.

Have a look at [SwingUtilities invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
Runnable newThread = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     }
 };
```

You can create a thread this way showed above.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the file IO in a background thread. And you can use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to ensure setting the label text is done in the EDT. Or you can just use the [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) convenience class that does this all for you.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need a separate thread. Take a look at [JProgressBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) and some [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ProgressBar.htm):

Answer (score 2):

Use a SwingWorker for the long running task. Then you can publish the text when the label needs to be updated.

Read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more background information.